# Lord and Prof titles

Tags: writing

Someone has a title Lord and is a Professor.  How will I address a letter?  And what will the correct manner be after Dear?

Comment: Please add a country tag. I assume they are from the UK?

Comment: https://www.debretts.com/expertise/forms-of-address/professions/ deals with exactly this case when it gets down to "professors"

Comment: Have you found and fixed the problem? If so, have the answers below led you to the solution? Please vote to accept an answer (using the green tick button next to the question) so this question is not bumped up once in a while and can be removed from the unanswered question list. You may even add your own solution and accept that after 48 hours! If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at this link, [Professions](https://www.debretts.com/expertise/forms-of-address/professions/), as provided by [erstwhile editor](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109787/lord-and-prof-titles#comment287624_109787) in the comments to your question, the answer would be *Professor Lord [Such-and-such]*:

> If a professor is also a member of the peerage, or a knight or dame, the academic style and title may be combined as ‘Professor Lord Ryder’ or ‘Professor Dame Elizabeth Pulteney’. He/she may prefer to be known by title alone.

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" form of address, as noted by another answer is "Professor Lord". However, the person in question is likely to use a less unwieldy title. Given he is a professor and a peer, there are probably ample press releases, news articles and interviews with him, and you should also look at his biography on his institution's page.

Most likely, he goes by just "Professor" in an academic context. Most likely, his reply email to you will just be signed with his first name. British academics are for the most part quite relaxed about titles. You shouldn't worry about it too much.